# Reverse a CSS animation once it completes

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I have a CSS animation and what I would like to do is have the animation reverse once the initial animation has completed. Here's what I have tried so far:

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  $('.animation-container').addClass('animate');
});

$(function() {
    var animationCount = 0;
    $(".animation-container").one("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function () {
        animationCount++
        if (animationCount === 2) {
          $('.animation-container').addClass('reverse');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.animation-container > div {
  display:block;
  background:#000;
  width:20px;
  height:30px;
}

.animation-container.animate {
  animation:rotateOuter 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
  .animation-container.reverse {
    animation:rotateOuter 2s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction: reverse;
  }

.animation-container.animate .top {
  animation:rotateInner 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
  .animation-container.reverse .top {
    animation:rotateInner 2s ease-in-out;
    animation-direction:reverse;
  }

@keyframes rotateOuter {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-20deg);
    }
}

@keyframes rotateInner {
    0% {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform:rotate(-30deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The idea here was to add a class with `animation-direction:reverse;` to the element once the first animation has completed, unfortunately it's not working as planned and just goes back to the default non-animated state.

Comment: Since you want to reverse it right away, why don't you just make the entire thing one animation?

Comment: @Huangism I considered that, but unfortunately it doesn't work since I am applying animations to more than 1 element with a delay. So what happens is the first animation plays and then reverses and then the second animation plays and then reverses if I go that route.

Comment: I played around with for a little bit and I came up with https://jsfiddle.net/cLyojfow/ I am sure you can adjust it to get what you want

Comment: @Huangism it's close, but what I'm looking for is `inner rotation > outer rotation > outer reverse > inner reverse`. Currently it's going `inner rotation > outer rotation > inner reverse > outer reverse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the entire thing one animation. The key is modifying the animation frames and delays so it works to your requirement

```
$('.animation-container').addClass('animate');
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('.animation-container').addClass('animate');

});
```

```css
.animation-container > div {
  display: block;
  background: #000;
  width: 20px;
  height: 30px;
}

.animation-container.animate {
  animation: rotateOuter 4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}


.animation-container.animate .top {
  animation: rotateInner 4s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateOuter {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotateInner {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animation-container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only with css :

```css
.element.anim {
  animation: 0.5s linear 0s forwards alternate slide-top, 0.5s linear 3.5s forwards reverse slide-top;
}

.element {
  color: #856404;
  background-color: #fff3cd;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 300px;
}

@keyframes slide-top {
  from{
    transform: translateY(20px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    to {
        transform: translateY(0px);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="element anim">
  <p>I'm a alert !</p>
</div>
```